# MSBUILD.MERGE.TASK error in ms dynamics crm plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

The "MSBuild.ILMerge.Task" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Compiler, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 2):

NuGet `ilmerge` from version 3 also includes `System.Compilers.dll` file (besides `ILMerge.exe`), so if you used version 2 and only copied `ILMerge.exe` to some other place for later use, now you need to copy `System.Compilers.dll` as well

Comment: OMG, your information just saved my day. Thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

The Nuget package for [MSBuild.ILMerge.Task](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.ILMerge.Task/) (version 1.0.5) states:

> MS Dynamics CRM users: merging in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk may crash your plugin, exclude it from the merge with Copy Local=false.

An [additional article](https://www.thrives.be/dynamics-365-ce/external-assemblies-dynamics-crm-plugins-ilmerge/) I found says that this assembly (and a few others) should be excluded (they used a picture in their article, hence the screenshot rather than a quote):

[image: CRM DLLs]

Perhaps try excluding Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (and maybe the other two .DLLs if you are using them) from the merge as stated.